# Deploy from S3 to IIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am new to DevOps and creating a sample CI/CD pipeline in AWS. Once CI is successful, the code should be moved to S3 bucket. I have to write an appspec.yml file to deploy artifacts from S3 to IIS.

Here I have few queries:
(1) Once CI is successful, are the files moved to S3 bucket as .zip?
(2) Where should I keep the appspec.yml? 
(3) What should the appspec.yml code look like so that CodeDeploy reads it and deploys the artifacts to IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Codedeploy, then you should zip the file locally, upload to S3 and then register the revision against your deployment group.

The appspec.yml is always found in the root folder of the deploy package.

Here is a sample appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
   - source: \index.html
   destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

This will deploy index.html to the default document root.

Your deployment package / zip file will contain appspec.yml and index.html in the root folder.

Comment: Thanks for the same. One more small issue is that once I run the deployment, it fails after sometime. It shows: Failed due to HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS. I have only one EC2 instance running.

Comment: Check the deployment events in the log.